# Can we Update all columns excluding one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

I tried the below code but its not working.

```
MERGE INTO Target as t
USING Source as s
ON s.Position = t.Position
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET * [except Created]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT *
```

Comment: No, this syntax is not supported.  You need to list the columns.

Comment: Such a syntax is not supported, but you can achieve something similar using dynamic SQL by creating your list of columns from the information_schema.columns table.

Comment: Depends what your benefits/issues will be, you could block/reverse the update of the column using a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the same column names in both tables something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(64),
@TargetTableName varchar(64),
@SourceTableName varchar(64),
@KeyColumn varchar(64),
@ExclusionColumn varchar(64),
@ColumnList varchar(1024),
@UpdateColumnList varchar(8000),
@SourceColumnList varchar(8000),
@Statement nvarchar(max)

SET @SchemaName='dbo'
SET @TargetTableName='Target'
SET @SourceTableName='Source'
SET @KeyColumn='Position'
SET @ExclusionColumn='Created'
 

SELECT @ColumnList = STUFF((
    select  ',' + COLUMN_NAME 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName 
    and TABLE_NAME=@TableName 
    and COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName),COLUMN_NAME,'isComputed')=0  
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @UpdateColumnList = STUFF((
    select  ',' + COLUMN_NAME +'=source.'+COLUMN_NAME  
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName 
    and TABLE_NAME=@TableName 
    and COLUMN_NAME not in (@ExclusionColumn,@KeyColumn)
    and COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName),COLUMN_NAME,'isComputed')=0  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @SourceColumnList = STUFF((
    select  ',' + 'source.'+COLUMN_NAME 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA=@SchemaName 
    and TABLE_NAME=@TableName 
    and COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName),COLUMN_NAME,'isComputed')=0  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

 

SET @Statement = 'MERGE ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TargetTableName +  ' AS Target USING (SELECT ' +
@ColumnList + ' FROM  '+ @SchemaName +'.' + @SourceTableName +  ') AS source  ' +
' ON (target.'+@KeyColumn+'= source.'+@KeyColumn+')' +
' WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET '+ @UpdateColumnList +
' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT('+@ColumnList+')
VALUES ('+@SourceColumnList+');'
 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Statement
```